# Obstacle avoidance with navigation stack without map!

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, sonar, avoidance

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got a little robot with 4 sonar sensor, is it possible to do obstacle avoidance without have a map? I've just finish to configure navigation stack and setting up launch files, but now i'm stuck. Thank u!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239870/obstacle-avoidance-with-navigation-stack-without-map!/) by [Oper](https://answers.ros.org/users/27436/oper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2016-07-19

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hemanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/39363/hemanth/) on 2020-02-03**:
Hey, Were you able to figure out how to approach this? I appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am assuming that you are trying to use dwa_local_planner provided by navigation stack and
given a global plan to follow and a costmap, the local planner produces velocity commands to send to a mobile base. But you can code your own obstacle avoidance

check out costmap and global planner's wiki

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2016-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Oper](https://answers.ros.org/users/27436/oper/) on 2016-07-25**:
Hello cagatay! Can you explain better? I have local planner, global costmap and local costmap configured, what should i do now?